# Limits to psionic power augmentation in DnD 3.5

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

Is there a limit as to how many power points a psion can use to augment a power?

As an example, the power Swarm of crystals has the following description:

> Thousands of tiny crystal shards spray 
>   forth in an arc from your hand. These 
>   razorlike crystals slice everything in 
>   their path. Anyone caught in the cone 
>   takes 3d4 points of slashing damage.
>     Augment: For every additional 
>   power point you spend, this power’s 
>   damage increases by 1d4 points.

Does that mean that if one has 30 power points to spare he could use them all to augment the power for an extra 30d4 points of damage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same confusion for a while, but thankfully, that's not the case.  You can only spend a number of power points equal to your level on any particular manifest.

> Some powers allow you to spend more than their base cost to achieve an improved effect, or augment the power. The maximum number of points you can spend on a power (for any reason) is equal to your manifester level.

- [Psionic Powers Overview – Power Points (d20srd)](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm#powerPoints)
- Psionics – Power Points (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* pg. 63)

Note that some abilities, such as a Wilder's [*Wild Surge*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/classes/wilder.htm#wildSurge) can increase your manifester level, and thereby, the amount you can augment.

Comment: Is this also present in the books?

Comment: @Khaal I *believe* it's in the 3.5 book ([*Complete* Psionics Handbook](http://www.amazon.com/Complete-Psionic-Dungeons-Roleplaying-Supplement/dp/0786939117/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1327672548&sr=8-2)), but it's possible that it was Errata.  I wouldn't use the 3.0 book ([Psionics Handbook](http://www.amazon.com/Psionics-Handbook-Dungeons-Dragons-Roleplaying/dp/0786918357/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1327672575&sr=8-3)) because it had no regard for game balance.

Comment: @C.Ross. You are right: that information is for sure in the _Complete_ Psionics Hanbook, and I think you can find it in its 3.0 counterpart too.

Comment: Can't say for certain as I currently don't have access to the book, but I recall this rule actually being introduced in the Expanded Psionics Handbook. Complete Psionic is a companion to this book and was released later.

Comment: *sigh* I have the original Psionics Handbook, but it's packed up somewhere.  I'll check when I find it.

Comment: It is absolutely in the Expanded Psionics Handbook -- it's super fundamental to the balance of the system.

Comment: Just a note here for any future users: there are two primary, first-party 3.5 books for Psionics, the *Expanded Psionics Handbook* (XPH) and *Complete Psionics* (CPsi). XPH is widely regarded as one of the best-designed books for 3.5, and is available for free as part of the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/index.htm). CPsi is often considered one of the *worst* books for 3.5, full of useless filler (e.g. some 50 different feats that just allow a new Mind Blade shape), some unnecessary nerfs (*astral construct*), some broken powers (*synchronicity*), and a general lack of worthwhile options.

Comment: @KRyan Good point.  I was thinking of the XPH, not sure why I had CPsi on the brain when I wrote that comment.